# Understanding how to avoid vue/require-prop-type-constructor warning in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am controlling a Tabview with a boolean variable `isTabsEnabled` to toggle displaying of tabs. This prop is passed as child to the screens using it, this is the parent file,

```
export{
  props:{
    isTabsEnabled: true
  }
}
```

ESLint throws the error `vue/require-prop-type-constructor`, I tried using `propsData`, this removes the warning message, but the functionality breaks.

Any suggestion on how can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to specify the prop type:

```
props: {
  isTabsEnabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me to relevant documentation? I couldn't find a relevant post.

Comment: [Prop definitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-definitions-essential) in the style guide and [vue/require-prop-type-constructor](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/require-prop-type-constructor.md) in the eslint-plugin-vue docs.

Comment: @DecadeMoon how about `types` `props: { foo: { types: [null, String] } }` is a valid code, but `eslint` catches it as a fail. How can I solve that?

Comment: @AdamOrlov That means `foo` can be any type (`null`) or a string, so it's redundant.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes but it can only be `null` or `String` it can not be `Object` or `Array` or `Boolean`. That is why it its not redundant. Only I don't understand why `eslint` doesn't approve that.

Comment: @Adam Because you cannot use `null` here to mean "require the value to be null"; Vue treats `null` as meaning "any value". You have to use `validator` for this kind of assertion.

Comment: @DecadeMoon ooook, I get it now! Thank you 